# how to access a div in a dynamically injected iframe through chrome extension using js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am injecting an iframe(`newframe`) in the main dom through a chrome extension. Now, I want to access the div(`id='contentDiv'`), present in the html file of the injected iframe and change its `innerHTML` to 'content'. I am sending a message from *background.js*, and on receiving it, following code is run:-

**manifest.json**

```
//some code
"web_accessible_resources": [
       "Frame.html"
   ],

"content_scripts": [
   {
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["script.js"]
   }
  ],

 "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "https://foo.com/"
  ]
 //some code
```

**script.js**

```
var newframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 //some settings for the iframe
newFrame.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("Frame.html");
document.body.appendChild(newFrame);

var doc = newframe.contentWindow.document;
var contentDiv = doc.getElementById('contentDiv');
contentDiv.innerHTML = "coupons";
```

On using this code, even the iframe fails to be injected and an error comes up `Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null`. I believe everything is alright with `manifest.json`, since iframe was being injected earlier.

Comment: Simply put the last three lines into `newFrame.onload = () => { ...... }`

Comment: Now, we have a new error. `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLIFrameElement.noti_iframe.onload`

Comment: Looks like your frame had a different src, which you didn't show in the question. In that case you'll have to declare a content script in manifest.json that runs on the URLs matching the iframe, and it'll be able to access the iframe contents. Then it can send the results via messaging.

Comment: @wOxxOm The code shown earlier is present in `script.js` itself. I have updated the answer with the relevant part of the `manifest.json`. I can update the whole manifest.json, if there's a need.

Comment: Indeed this is a cross-origin frame so you can't directly access its contents. Since the frame runs your extension page, you don't need an additional content script: simply use messaging from the main content script to the iframe e.g. newFrame.postMessage({foo: 'bar'}, '*') and process this message inside iframe's window.addEventListener('message', event => ...........). You can find examples easily.